# Can't set sweetalert options on typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert

Installed packages:

```
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0"
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
"sweetalert": "^2.0.8"
"@types/sweetalert": "^1.1.28"
```

How I'm using sweetalert:

```
import * as swal from "sweetalert";
//...
doSomething() {
    const options = {
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Some text here!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        showConfirmButton: true
    };
    swal(options, (remove) => { });
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

- VSC IntelliSense:

> 'Argument of type '{ title: string; text: string; type: string;
>   showCancelButton: boolean; showConfirmButton: boolea...' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'Settings & PromtModalSettings'.
>   Type '{ title: string; text: string; type: string; showCancelButton:
>   boolean; showConfirmButton: boolea...' is not assignable to type
>   'PromtModalSettings'.
>       Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
>         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'PromtType'.' at: '101,14' source: 'ts'

- TypeScript compiles, but on browser console, I get this:

> ERROR Error: SweetAlert: Unexpected 2nd argument (function (remove) {...

I tried setting the `options` type as `SweetAlert.Settings & SweetAlert.AlertModalSettings`, but I can't access the namespace `SweerAlert`, and also tried `any`. None of them worked.

**How can I set these options to sweetalert?**

[TS type file.](https://github.com/slavovojacek/adbrain-typescript-definitions/blob/master/sweetalert/sweetalert.d.ts)

Comment: Did you try `import swal from 'sweetalert'` instead of `import * as swal`?

Comment: I get this: `Module '"sweetalert"' has no default export`

Comment: Go to `sweetalert.d.ts` and change `export = swal` -> `export default swal;`. This issue has been reported on SweetAlert github recently and the fix is committed. I just don't know how it's not in the latest npm package. Then you can do `import swal from 'sweetalert'`. However, my suggestion is to go with SweetAlert2

Comment: Sorry, but what would be the difference between `import swal from 'sweetalert'` and `import * as swal`?

Comment: It is not accepting the same attributes, nesting buttons with other attribute is giving errors.

Comment: Both returning error... well... I'll try something else. Thank you!

Comment: `swal(options, (remove) => { });` I am not sure what `remove` parameters is. Is there a doc for this syntax?

Comment: `remove` is a boolean that tells if I chose ok. See on signature: `(settings: Settings & AlertModalSettings, callback?: (isConfirm: boolean) => any): void;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sweetalert does not need to install types. It already has it implemented. When installing types, I was getting a conflict between the orignal types, then getting errors. I just removed `@types/sweetalert` and everything worked just like the examples in their [site](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/).

Comment: i am stuck in this error since hours, so you're saying remove `@types/sweetalert`, please can you specify more from where should i remove this `@types/sweetalert` since i installed swal with this command `npm install sweetalert --save` and then importing it in my component like this `import swal`from 'sweetalert';`@types/sweetalert`

Comment: I too don't have `@types/sweetalert` in my package.json & still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix is :

Directly go to the project folder then \node_modules\sweetalert\typings\sweetalert.d.ts
In this you will find this line

```html
const swal: SweetAlert;
```

just delete or comment it.. 
The error is sorted..

Comment: This might be a quick and dirty fix, but definitely not a good one. The changes will be gone after updating the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than messing with the node_modules why not simply cast the options as SweetAlertOptions:

```
 const options = {
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Some text here!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        showConfirmButton: true
    } as SweetAlertOptions;
```